# Why does button not properly progress when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, innerhtml

I have some Javascript I am looking at and the js code says:

```
function buttonClicked(buttonid)  {
  console.log("entered case statement");
  var UrlString = "templates/story/pt1/Start.html";
  switch(buttonid) {
    case "YesStart":
        UrlString = "templates/story/pt1/YesStart.html";
        loadDoc(UrlString);
        break;
    case "NoStart":
        UrlString = "templates/story/pt1/NoStart.html";
        loadDoc(UrlString);
        break;
    case "ContinueStart":
        UrlString = "templates/story/pt1/ContinueStart.html";
        loadDoc(UrlString);
        break;
    default:
        document.getElementById("storybox").innerHTML = "<p>We didn't get to that part yet. Click if you want to</p><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' id='nobtn' onclick='buttonClicked('YesStart')'>Restart</button>";
        <!-- Output error info -->
        console.log(buttonid);
    };
```

But when I click my button it never restarts and I don't get to go back to where I was at the beginning before I pressed my button. Can someone help me make the button click the way it should?

Most relevant HTML in `index.html`:

```
<!-- MVC starts here-->
  <div class="storybox" id="storybox">
  <script src="js/story.js"></script>
  </div>
<!-- MVC ends here -->

<!-- Libraries -->
<script src="./js/vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/vendor/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Modules -->
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/story.js"></script>

<div>
<p id="copyright-note">Copyright © Sassafras Associated Ltd 2016. We will shortly be accepting Dogecoin donations ready for phase two.</p>
</div>
```

Template `YesStart.html` is:

```
<p>[Some text]</p>
<p>[Some more text]</p>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-success' id='continuebtn' onclick='buttonClicked("ContinueStart")'>Continue</button>
```

Comment: Sorry.I am talking please add relevent html and how you calling buttonClicked?

Comment: Oh. I maybe talk to my friend he writes a lot of the code I just look over and help him sometimes

Comment: Is your `onclick` handler being called? If so what is the contents of `loadDoc()` It looks like its being passed a url to do something with which i guess would actually do the redirect.

Comment: What does loadDoc() function do?

Comment: It's a jQuery function

Comment: The ```onclick``` handler is being called, yes, it's just the default case which seems to be behaving strangely, I think it's to do with the number of quotes, but the ```loadDoc()``` does look a bit strange I know

Comment: onclick='buttonClicked('YesStart')' That might be a problem, if you add that as html, i suspect the single quotes around YesStart may break the single quotes wrapping the function. You could try onclick=\"buttonClicked('YesStart')\" and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: I'll have a look and see, thanks. I usually use a different language to call my handler so it's a bit weird for me.